# I'm tyring to add image attribute to product by installer

Tags: sql, setup, installer

I'm trying to add an image attribute by the following code:

```
<?php
$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'catalog_setup');
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product','my_image_attribute_1',
    array (
        'group'             => 'General',
        'type'              => 'varchar',
        'frontend'          => 'catalog/product_attribute_frontend_image',
        'label'             => 'Additional product image',
        'input'             => 'media_image',
        'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
        'visible'           => true,
        'required'          => false,
        'user_defined'      => false,
        'configurable'      => false,
        'visible_on_front'  => true,
        'default'           => '',
        'class'             => '',
        'source'            => ''
    )
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

The attribute is created but I can't see it on product edit page.

**UPDATE:**

Ok this code adds only a radio Button to default image gallery.
Hm I wanted to create a custom upload form for a single image...

Answer (score 1):

Did you added in attribute set?
**catalog->attributes->manage attribute sets -> select your set name**
then drag and drop from right to left in attribute group like "general"